# Image to base64: Why don't I get the same return value while calling the same function in Python?

Tags: python, image, return, base64

I am sorry for stupid question, but I am a newbie in Python and I didn't succeed in finding answer on my question neither on stackoverflow nor on google.

For instance I want to get image from url and transfer it to string in base64 format. I use urllib and io modules to transform a link into object 
and then I twice call my "tob64" function:

```
import base64
import urllib
import io

fd = urllib.urlopen("http://p2pmailing.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Fashion-And-Modern-Youth.jpg")
img = io.BytesIO(fd.read())

def tob64(image):
    pic = image.read()
    b64 = base64.b64encode(pic)
    return b64

A = tob64(img)
B = tob64(img)

print A==B
```

I ran this code I and I get FALSE statement. 
When I print out variable A, I get actual answer which is string.
When I print out variable B I don't get anything as return value.
Nevertheless when I'm asking the type of B it prints out " type 'str' ". 
So actually it is stored somewhere, but I can't get it. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after first `image.read()` EOF is reached and next `image.read()` will return empty string because there's nothing more to read. You can use `image.seek(0)` before read to read whole file again.